# Making Illustrator layer combination script

Tags: loops, recursion, jsx, combinations, adobe-illustrator

I need to make a jsx script for illustrator. I need to a script that do the following:

Take all sublayers from main layers, and recursive make layer combinations.

Layer hierarchi would be like this:

```
Main layer 1
    White text
    Black text
    Purple text

Main layer 2
    Red background
    Green background
    Blue background

E.g.:
    Red background + white text
    Red background + Black text
    Red background + Red text
    Green background + white text
    Green background + Black text
    Green background + Red text
    Blue background + white text
    Blue background + Black text
    Blue background + Red text
```

So I would like to recursively go through the layers sublayers, and make combination from those. There could be many layers with sublayers in them, this is just an example.

I hope all this makes sense.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far and explain what exactly the problem you are facing is?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it doesn't even need any recursion. You can just copy all the items from a top layer to the next bottom layer and remove the top layer afterward. And repeat it while there is more than one layer in the document.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// repeat the function for two top layers while there is more that one layer
while (doc.layers.length > 1) main();


// paste every sublayer of a top layer into the syblayers of the second layer
function main() {

    // top layer (source) and its sublayers
    var src_layer = doc.layers[0];
    var src_sublayers = src_layer.layers;
    var src_sublayers_names = [];
    for (var i=0; i<src_sublayers.length; i++) src_sublayers_names.push(src_sublayers[i].name);

    // second layer (destination) and its sublayers
    var dest_layer = doc.layers[1];
    var dest_sublayers = dest_layer.layers;
    var dest_sublayers_names = [];
    for (var i=0; i<dest_sublayers.length; i++) dest_sublayers_names.push(dest_sublayers[i].name);

    // put objects from the source sublayers into the destination sublayers
    for (var i=0; i<dest_sublayers_names.length; i++) {
        var dest_sublayer = dest_sublayers[dest_sublayers_names[i]];

        for (var j=0; j<src_sublayers_names.length; j++) {
            var src_sublayer = src_layer.layers[src_sublayers_names[j]];

            // select all items on the source sublayer and the destination sublayer
            src_sublayer.hasSelectedArtwork = true;
            dest_sublayer.hasSelectedArtwork = true;
            app.copy();
            app.selection = null;

            // make a new destination sublayer and paste the items into it
            var new_dest_sublayer = dest_sublayers.add();
            new_dest_sublayer.name = (dest_sublayer.name + ' + ' + src_sublayer.name);
            app.activeDocument.activeLayer = new_dest_sublayer;
            app.executeMenuCommand('pasteFront');
            app.selection = null;
        }
    }

    // remove the source layer with its sublayers
    src_layer.remove();

    // remove the old destination sublayers
    for (var i=0; i<dest_sublayers_names.length; i++) {
        dest_layer.layers[dest_sublayers_names[i]].remove();
    }

}
```

Start (3 layers, 8 sublayers):

[image]

The result (18 combinations):

[image]

---

If you want to save all the sublayers as separate AI files here is the function:

```
function save_sublayers() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var sublayers = doc.layers[0].layers;
    for (var i=0; i<sublayers.length; i++) {
        var sublayer = sublayers[i];
        sublayer.hasSelectedArtwork = true;
        app.copy();
        app.selection = null;
        var file = File(doc.path + '/' + sublayer.name + '.ai');
        var new_doc = app.documents.add();
        app.paste();
        new_doc.saveAs(file);
        new_doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }
}
```

You can call the function `save_sublayers()` after the line `while (doc.layers.length > 1) main();`

It saves all items from the sublayers of the first (and only) layer into separate AI files into the parent folder of current document. File names are the same as sublayers names.

Comment: Nice solution. But I want to keep the layers as is, so it's non-destructive to the layer structure.

Comment: For this case I'd propose to make a temporary copy of the original document, process the temporary document, then move the result sublayers into the original document (into a new layer, I suppose) and close the temporary document. It can be done manually pretty easy, or with a script as well.

Comment: Though, it just occurred me, it can be done within one document, too. A script could make copies of all the layers of current document first, put the names of copied layers into an array, and then iterate through the array in the same way as it does with layers in my first example. Let me know if you need it.

Comment: The best case would be like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWMTaxm4rfk

Comment: So you can just buy the script for $30 or $50. It looks like the author is even ready to sell it for your price if you think the price is too high. Why would you try this option?

Comment: I just added the function to save all the sublayers of the top layer of current document as separate AI files. Now the script does almost the same job as the one from Youtube, except it changes the current document. So you need to be carefull and don't save the document if you have no copy of it.

Comment: Sure i could just buy it, but where is the fun in that? :)  I want to get bettet at coding this kind of stuff.  I will try your script Yuri, thanks for the effort :)